How to take data from HTML Inputs and use them in a form?
I am trying to get the user's login and password from the HTML template  and use these inputs for processing. I want to use the inputs from the HTML template and not the usual Django forms, like:
<label class="form-label">Username</label>
{{ form.username }}
<span>{{ form.errors.username }}</span>

I had signin.html file:
{% extends 'app_main/base.html' %}

{% block auth %}
{% load static %}

<section id="signin" class="wrapper style1 fade-up">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <div class="split style1">
            <section>
                {% if form.errors and form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="fields">
                        <ul style="list-style: none;">
                            <li>
                                <div class="field half">
                                    <p></p>
                                    <label class="form-label">Username</label>
                                    {{ form.username }}
                                    <span>{{ form.errors.username }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="field half">
                                    <p></p>
                                    <label class="form-label">Password</label>
                                    {{ form.password }}
                                    <span>{{ form.errors.password }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="small text-left">
                                    <p></p>
                                    <p class="signin">
                                        <a href="{% url 'users:password_reset' %}" class="text-center">
                                            <i>Forgot Password?</i>
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="" class="button submit">Submit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}

And it works great with the forms.py file.
But I want to use a more beautiful template.
This is a part of more beautiful HTML template:
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="mb-[22px]">
<input type="username" placeholder="Username"
                                   class="w-full px-5 py-3 text-base transition bg-transparent border rounded-md outline-none border-stroke dark:border-dark-3 text-body-color dark:text-dark-6 placeholder:text-dark-6 focus:border-primary dark:focus:border-primary focus-visible:shadow-none"
/>
</div>
<div class="mb-[22px]">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password"
                                   class="w-full px-5 py-3 text-base transition bg-transparent border rounded-md outline-none border-stroke dark:border-dark-3 text-body-color dark:text-dark-6 placeholder:text-dark-6 focus:border-primary dark:focus:border-primary focus-visible:shadow-none"
/>
</div>

This is the file forms.py:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.forms import CharField, TextInput, EmailField, EmailInput, PasswordInput
from users.validators import validate_email


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = CharField(
        max_length=50,
        min_length=3,
        required=True,
        widget=TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    )
    email = EmailField(
        max_length=320,
        validators=[validate_email],
        required=True,
        widget=EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    )
    password1 = CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    )
    password2 = CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = CharField(
        max_length=50,
        min_length=3,
        required=True,
        widget=TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    )
    password = CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "password")

How can I properly pair these more beautiful template and my forms.py files?

I think you're just missing the FormView. The following example makes some assumptions about what you intend to do with the form. For example, I read your statement "and not the usual Django forms" to mean you want more control and so the below proposed example includes logging in the user. As my example is written, it competes with your LoginForm because you inherit from AuthenticationForm which also completes the login within it's clean() method. That said, please remember to adjust this example according to your actual needs.
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import LoginForm

class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'  # replace with your login template
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')  # replace with your success url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
            return super().form_valid(form)

        form.add_error(None, "Invalid username or password")
        return super().form_invalid(form)


Thank you for your response. I'm sorry, I'm a beginner, and it's not quite clear to me how I can use the LoginView class. If I understand correctly, I can add it to the forms.py file? Here is what my forms.py file looks like now: 
I will also need to do the same with the registration form. Therefore, it may be better to do it comprehensively. Please explain the steps you recommend in more detail.

@Serg , thank you for clarifying. I think the most appropriate response is to direct you to this excellent discussion on how to add authentication to your site: https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/authentication_authorization/#log-in-users. I hope this is helpdul!

Thank you, but that's not exactly what I need either. I've updated my request, maybe I didn't express myself correctly at first.
